# What is a good debugger for native (C/C++) applications on the Mac?

Tags: visual-studio, macos, debugging, windbg, gud

I'm a native developer switching to the Mac from Windows. I have a lot of experience debugging using Windbg (CDB-GUD on Emacs) and Visual Studio and was wondering which debugger on the Mac would give me the closest experience? I'm specifically looking for the following features:

- Ability to debug arbitrary executables (VS lets me do this by setting the debug target to any executable).
- Customizable keyboard shortcuts. At least f5, f9, f10, f11, Shift f11. I don't care so much about the rest.

I don't use VS to do any kind of editing so that is not important to me.

The most comfortable setup so far has been running Emacs GUD - which I do on Windows too using CDB-GUD, but wonder if there is something better out there.

Update:
I understand GDB is the debugger most people use. I guess my original question was poorly worded. I really meant to ask what debugger GUI would give me an environment really similar to Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2):

Most people use gdb, either from the console or from Xcode -- the latter being much like you are used to in windows I imagine. LLVM also has a debugger, also available in the Xcode GUI.